# The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404, webclient, downloadstring

I am running this piece of code to get the source code (as string) of my [webpage.](http://www.kickstart.gr)

The problem is why this function returns 404 error?

```
Private Function getPageSource(ByVal URL As String) As String
    Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient()
    Dim strSource As String = webClient.DownloadString(URL)
    webClient.Dispose()
    Return strSource
End Function
```

Comment: 1) for the source you mean the HTML right? 2) Could you paste one sample URL?

Comment: The sample url is http://www.kickstart.gr/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

using System; 
using System.IO; 
using System.Net; 
using System.Text;

```
public static void GetFile 
        ( 
        string strURL, 
        string strFilePath 
        ) 
    { 

        WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(strURL);  

        WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();  

        Stream ReceiveStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream(); 

        Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"); 

        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader( ReceiveStream, encode ); 

        string strResponse=readStream.ReadToEnd(); 

        StreamWriter oSw=new StreamWriter(strFilePath); 

        oSw.WriteLine(strResponse); 

        oSw.Close(); 

        readStream.Close(); 

        myWebResponse.Close(); 

    }
```

Comment: Pardon me, but for what reason should i try this solution?